# LM317 digitally-controlled constant current power supply

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-limiting, constant-current, lm317, atx

I'm designing and simulating (with the intention of building) a lab power supply. I like a challenge so I'm trying to make it digitally controlled (also because I'm a programmer). I'm doing this for the sake of learning electronics, not because I think I can do any better than a cheap commercial solution.

I want to use LM317s to set the voltage and limit the current, because they're cheap and easily available. The voltage bit is easy, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to handle the current limiting given the LM317's 1.25V minimum voltage between **OUT** and **ADJ**.

This is what I have for the current-limiting part:

[image]

It's based on a [video by EEVblog](https://youtu.be/CIGjActDeoM?t=1604). In his video, he's got an LT3080 regulator chip (which doesn't have the 1.25V minimum output voltage), so the circuit would theoretically work fine for him.

In my circuit, assume the lower 5V supply (**V4**) is a filtered PWM signal from a microcontroller. If the microcontroller is outputting a 0% duty cycle, then there'll be 0V at the bottom of the voltage divider formed by **R9** and **R10**. If there's 10V at the top of the divider, then that means the op amp labelled **X5** will get 5V on its non-inverting input. The voltage divider on its inverting input means it will have a gain of 2, and output 10V. That way it will try to keep 0 amps flowing through the resistor **R13**.

If the micro outputs a 100% duty cycle PWM signal, that will be filtered to a steady 5V, divided to 1V (by **R15** and **R8**), buffered by op amp **X7** and added to the bottom of voltage divider **R9**/**R10**. This (I think) should add 0.5V volts to the 5V in the voltage divider and give 5.5V. Then that's multiplied by 2 by op amp **X5** to give 11 volts, which is 1 volt above the voltage measured after **R13**.

In theory, this should make 1A flow if the load draws that much, and limit it to 1A if the load wants more.

**SO.**

The question is, how can I make this general concept work with an LM317? I believe if I can figure out how to reduce the voltage out of op amp **X5** by 1.25V, then it will work, but I'm not sure how to achieve that. I have a -12V rail in the ATX PSU that I'm using, and plenty of op amps, but I don't know how to take advantage of that.

This is what I think I want to do:

[image]

It's very likely that I'm drastically overcomplicating things, so please tell me if there's a simpler way.

Comment: The LM317 also has build-in overcurrent protection so I would say that you don't need R13 **unless** you want an **adjustable** maximum output current.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie How so? Overcurrent protection doesn't give me a way to measure the current. R13 is a shunt resistor so that I can measure the current and limit it with the op amp.

Comment: That is correct, I was under the impression that you wanted to adjust the output **voltage** instead of the current. I do not see how you will set the voltage. I see that Dave suggests using a 2nd LT3080 in series to set the voltage.

Comment: The LM317 and LT3080 behave in a similar way except that the LT3080 works at V(OUT) = V(SET) while the LM317 works at: V(OUT) = V(ADJ) + 1.25V which gives an offset in this circuit that is not easy to remove. I would suggest just using the LT3080 for this.

Comment: Why don't you simulate it; you appear to be using micro-cap to make the schematic.

Comment: The bigger question is what Vin/Vout Pmax range do you need in order to keep cool and regulate well.  Anything is possible. But this concept cannot do everthing.

Comment: "R13 is a shunt resistor so that I can measure the current and limit it with the op amp." So, why aren't you measuring the current through R13? All you are doing (if the circuit works) is to control the voltage across R16.

Comment: @Bimplerekkie The question is very specifically about current limiting. Not really sure where you got the impression I was trying to control voltage here. I am of course going to use a second LM317 in series to control the voltage, but that's not relevant here.

Comment: @Bimplerekkie I have to ask, did you read the question? I'm fully aware of the differences between the LT3080 and LM317 and the 1.25V offset. That's the entire point of this question.

Comment: @Andyaka I _am_ simulating it. That's..... literally the 4th word in my question...

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 That's not really important right now. I'll limit things to sensible values once I get it working in theory. Right now I just want to solve the problem.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Care to elaborate? Because I _am_ measuring the current across R13. Sure if goes through a voltage divide-by-2 and an op amp with a gain of 2, but it's still measuring that current.

Comment: @Clonkex - Ah. Sorry for confusing you. You are attempting to provide overcurrent protection, right? That can't happen when the load is fixed at some resistance such as 10 ohms. Ohm's Law applies. When the load resistance varies, unless you know what it is, you cannot know what the current is. The usual way to handle this is to make a differential measurement across R13, which IS fixed.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I don't really get what you're saying. I'm trying to build a digitally-controlled lab power supply, and this section of the circuit is intended to provide current limiting. Given that **R13** is a fixed, known value, it doesn't matter what the load is as long as I measure the voltage immediately after it. It's 1Ω, so a 1V drop means 1A is flowing. Since op amp **X5** is configured as a voltage follower with a gain of 2 (and we're measuring with a gain of 0.5), we're directly instructing the regulator what voltage to output, and therefore we don't need to measure before **R13**.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast But don't worry about it, I've come a long way in the past couple of days (I've gotten over most of the initial confusion so I'm learning fast) and I believe I have correctly understood the problem and designed a solution. I'll answer my own question when I've built the circuit up for realz, whether it works or not. Simulations show that it will work really nicely but obviously I won't know for sure until I try.

Comment: @Clonkex - "It's 1Ω, so a 1V drop means 1A is flowing." But the only way to know what the drop is, is by measuring the voltage on the other side of the resistor as well. And your circuit doesn't do that.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast It knows by assumption. It assumes that whatever the op amp tells the LM317 on **ADJ** is what will be on the output. I'm not the one to come up with this idea (see the video linked in my question) but after thinking some more I'm not sure it would be stable unless the op amp had exactly 0 offset voltage and the LM317 reliably had exactly 0 difference between **ADJ** and **OUT - 1.25V**. Otherwise the voltage would tend to climb all the way up to Vcc or down to GND. My new method should work perfectly, but as I say I'll post an answer when I get the kinks figured out.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Actually no I think it would be stable after all... Hmm...